# How to get upload/download speed with Java

Tags: java, linux

I want to get the current donload/upload speed in Java.
I need some information how I can use the data from `/proc/net/dev`

```
[root@laptop ~]# cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo: 2522296   27390    0    0    0     0          0         0  2522296   27390    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0: 206888698752 159544908    0    0    0     0          0      6415 24408080083 127074897    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0: 3008127954 2403692    0    0    0     0          0         0 247504697 2097580    0    0    0     0       0          0
[root@laptop ~]#
```

I suspect that I have to do do something like this:

```
CURRENT_Receive - PREV_Receive = current_speed
```

Can you give me some hint or code example?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your problem can be easily solved with bash script (`wget -O /dev/null some_url_of_big_file` for example). Then, if you want to get the result in your java code, you should create environment variable for it and call [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) in your java code.

Comment: About what? All steps seem to be easily googled. First, you use bash script to define your network speed and store it in environment variable. Second, you use `System.getenv()` to get access to env. variables in your java code.